# Vanilla JavaScript - Write / update a JSON file without prompting for a folder and name

Tags: javascript

Using **vanilla Javascript only**, I need the ability to create/update JSON files whose location and name are known to the code. So far, I found a working solution that allows me to create or update a file after the system prompts me to select the folder and filename. The code is:

```
async function Save_JSON_File() {

    // create a new handle
    newHandle = await window.showSaveFilePicker();
    var l = "mmm mmm "

    // create a FileSystemWritableFileStream to write to
    const writableStream = await newHandle.createWritable();
    
    // write our file
    await writableStream.write(l);
    
    // close the file and write the contents to disk.
    await writableStream.close();
}
```

This function, whose invocation must be triggered by a user "gesture" (e.g. click), would create/update the selected file and will write into it the string "*mmm mmm* ".

My interpretation is that `newHandle` receives an object containing the information (full path and filename) and attempted, with zero success, to manually create such object and update the required fields (path and full name).

**EDIT**

In my above description I should had added some (perhaps) crucial information. The application I'm building is not aimed to be deployed into an "internet-reachable" site. Instead, it will be stored into an external storage device (memory stick / external disk) and, except from two libraries (bootstrap and font-awesome) the whole thing will be completely local. It is an application that resembles Powerpoint presentations (well, just a very small set of functionalities of course).

I examined Rayno's suggestion as well as a library called "LowDB". I guess they both may provide what I need and, if so, I'll update this post with the results and how I did it.

Comment: do you think reading/writing arbitrary files in a browser without user "gesture" would not be a massive security issue? `Any suggestions on how to achieve this will be highly appreciated.` - create a browser that allows it

Comment: If you need to persist data either request user permission or use session/local storage

Comment: You could create a browser extension. You can try [File System API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API)

Comment: [Origin private file system (OPFS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API/Origin_private_file_system) might also be something you want to look into

Comment: Thank you @Reyno for your suggestion. I edited the question with some additional information.

Comment: Thank you @pilchard. I found a library that may do just that, LowDB.  Will update this post as soon as a conclusion is reached.

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

Browsers will not allow your code to trigger file saves without user gestures due to security problems. It's clear that in your case this would not be a security problem because everything is being done locally and in a trusted manner, but the browsers assume this to be unsafe. Let's see what the possible options are.

## Use a server

You can install a server which is able to read/write files according to your needs. Since you are already into Javascript, a Javascript-based server, such as NodeJS might spring to mind as a possibly viable option for your scenario.

How to read-write files in NodeJS: https://tutorialedge.net/nodejs/reading-writing-files-with-nodejs/

The page given above provides and explains the following code:

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("temp.txt", function(err, buf) {
  console.log(buf.toString());
});
```

Basically you require `fs` which is a resource for file streams into the `fs` file, read a file whose path is passed and in the callback, a `buf` buffer is being logged.

And this is given as the example as of how to write a file:

```
var fs = require("fs");

var data = "New File Contents";

fs.writeFile("temp.txt", data, (err) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log("Successfully Written to File.");
});
```

You again have `fs` and you are writing your `data` into a file. I slightly changed the example to only log success if there was no error.

Now that you see how a file is to be written in NodeJS, basically you will need to implement an API that allows you to pass the file paths you want to read/write from/to and perform the actions required and implement on the client-side AJAX requests that are sending the proper commands to the server and handling the answers received in a proper manner.

## Browser-extension

You can implement a browser-extension and use it on your local machines. This extension will need to have functions that do the file saving. Alternatively you can search for such extensions that may already exist.

## Do nothing

I know it sounds silly, but this is also a viable option in general, even if it's not viable for you. You can accept that what you intended is considered unsafe and expect your co-workers to click on a button to trigger file saves.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. If I need some kind of server, I have a small servlet (tomcat) that would do the job. The problem is that such type of servers require installation(s) at the side of the user. Imagine that I would give you a memory stick with the whole SW, you connect it to a computer with Windows (10) and simply run a small bat script, no SW installation of any kind. There is a (free) WAMP product "Uniform Server" which, so it looks, runs without the need of any installation. Will continue my research while keeping your idea in mind.

Comment: @FDavidov WAMP (Windows Apache MySQL PHP) is another possibility to have a server. Since it uses PHP as the server-side language, you could implement the file handling and API in PHP instead of NodeJS. This is also a feasible option. The reason for suggesting NodeJS earlier was that you were already into Javascript. But PHP is just as good to do the job.

Comment: Thanks again Lajos for your feedback. Unfortunately, I have 0 experience with PHP (not that I could not sit and learn, but...). On the other hand, I did develop servlets for tomcat and hence that would be a plausible path as well (I think). Other option could be to execute small programs from within the javascript (using the mechanism shown here: https://help.callassoftware.com/m/pdftoolbox/l/1413256-execute-external-application-via-javascript-function - Still need to verify it will work...).